# Borderlands The Pre-sequel one point wonders

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

What are the one point wonders for each of the characters?

By one point wonder I mean: a skill that with only one point can change a characters play style. Like the bleed effect for the gladiator: use of melee attack is probably increased a fair amount.

Comment: Play style is a very personal thing.  Do you have an example you can use?  Or how much it has to change in order for it to meet the definition of, "drastically"?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Isn't this something you could easily find on the Borderlands wikia? @Frank I think what he's referring to is the 1 point abilities that max out when you invest a point into them. Think Axton's Scorched Earth that adds Rocket Pods, or Zer0's B0re, etc.

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia He...could be.  Doesn't seem quite right, though; the skill tree would give you a list of those without any issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Athena

- **Phalanx**

  - Prismatic Aegis
  - Clear!
  - Wrath of the Goddess
- **Xiphos**

  - Rend
  - Epicenter
  - Blood Rush
- **Ceraunic Storm**

  - Maelstrom
  - Smite
  - Zeus' Rage
  - Hades' Shcakles

## Wilhelm

- ### **Hunter Killer**

  ### -
- ### **Cyber Commando**

  ### -
- ### **Dreadnought**

  ### -

    -

## Nisha

- ### **Law & Order**

  ### -
- ### **Fan the Hammer**
- **The Riflewoman**

## Claptrap

- **Boomtrap**

  - Second Wind [By Tediore]
  - I Am Rubber, You Are Glue
  - Livin' Near the Edge
- ### **I Love You Guys!**

  ### -

    -
- ### **Fragmented Fragtrap**

  ### -

  ### -

  -

## Jack (DLC)

- **The Hero of this Story**

  - You Have my Shield
  - Jack's Cache
  - On My Mark
  - Promote The Rank
- **Greater Good**

  - Diversify
  - Commitment
  - Accountability
  - Potential
  - Leadership
- **Free Enterprise**

  - Money Is Power
  - Merger
  - Laser Surplus
  - Sponsored By...

## Aurelia (DLC)

- **The Huntress**

  - Long - Range Killer
  - Silver Lining
  - Magic Bullet
  - Custom Loads
- **Cold Money**

  - Winter's Fury
  - Fragment Rain
  - Polar Vortex
  - Wintertide
- **Contractual Aristocracy**

  - Contractual Obligations
  - You First
  - Excellent Shot, madam
  - All Glory to the Master
  - A Backhand to Remember

Comment: Sorry, in a bit of editing and was copying a template over, apologies!